# how to reference a groovy variable within sh command

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

How I can I reference groovy variable within sh command?

> Script1.groovy: 23: unexpected token: $ @ line 23, column 24.
>        sh(script:zip -r ${BUILD_TAG}.zip src/*.py)

Command

```
sh(script:zip -r ${BUILD_TAG}.zip src/*.py)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need double quotes (`"`) to interpolate variables within strings in Groovy. Your updated step method `sh` would then have a value of `"zip -r ${BUILD_TAG}.zip src/*.py"` for the Map passed as the argument, and would appear fully as:

```
sh(script: "zip -r ${BUILD_TAG}.zip src/*.py")
```

However, with the installation of the [Pipeline Utility Steps Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-utility-steps), you can invoke the [native bindings step method](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#zip-create-zip-file) to zip the file:

```
zip(zipFile: "${BUILD_TAG}.zip",
    dir: 'src',
    glob: '*.py')
```

which would be more compatible and stable than the `sh` step method. For example, if your pipeline is executing on an agent where the zip executable is not named `zip`, is not directly in your path, does not accept `*` globbing, or does not accept `-r` as a valid flag (or possibly `-r` triggers undesired behavior), then your `sh` step method will be unsuccessful. However, the native bindings step method for zip will ensure your desired behavior is achieved regardless of environment, platform, etc.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please explain how this would be more stable than sh step?

Comment: @PunterVicky Sure; added a couple more sentences describing situations where first method would have issues and second method would succeed.

Comment: awesome! this is very helpful :)